# Is there a way in dialogFlow to change for all intents it's endInteraction to true?

Tags: dialogflow-es, api-ai

I have 700 intents in DialogFlow, and I want to enable end interaction flag in all of the intents. I wrote a script that downloads the entire agent and for every intent in this agent adds the key "endInteraction".

My problem is that when I download the entire agent I don't see endInteraction key even when I enabled it before manually.

Comment: I have the same problem. I wound up writing a script in the console that would loop through each intent and proxy click the controls on the dashboard.